# Are questions about playing space on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

Are questions about managing a physical play space on topic? I read through the current [on-topic page](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and it does not mention this topic. It seems like most of the topics are about the games themselves, and there's even a caveat the the game doesn't need to have a physical board (e.g. digital implementations of classic board games are on-topic).

Potential questions of this play space category could include questions about organizing physical pieces/cards, space requirements for playing specific games, and possibly even questions like [this question about standing tables/desks for playing board games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53453/do-sit-stand-board-gaming-tables-exist) (which could be off-topic for other reasons, but that's not the point of this meta question). Are any of these kinds of questions on-topic?

Comment: What kind of answers would you expect a question like that to attract?

Comment: Depends on the question, but I could see techniques for managing game pieces/collections. Answers on how to make complex games states more organized or less confusing. Then stretching it a bit more, secondary aspects regarding keeping a board/card game in good condition for replaying the game (card sleeves? long-term storage?).

Comment: (this linked question is a recommendation question, but I could imagine a question asking about table surfaces/materials that are best suited for playing a specific game)

Comment: "Does this exist" is not asking for a recommendation. Precedent. Useful. Upvoted. https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49912/does-a-game-recommendation-website-exist

Comment: @Jessy why are you leaving that comment on this meta post? If you think your question was wrongly closed, leave a comment on your post or create a new meta question arguing for why you think it should be reopened. The fact that your question is closed as recommendation is not relevant to the discussion here where I'm asking if the other aspect of your question (regarding board game tables/hardware) is on topic.